# Allow backorder for specific products based on a custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields

I tried allow backorders for certain products depending on a custom meta field with this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed','filter_woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 10, 3 );
 function filter_woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed( $allow_backorder, $product_id, $product ){

$custom_stock = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_custom_stock', true );

if ( ! empty ( $custom_stock ) ) {
    $allow_backorder = true;
}
return $allow_backorder;
}
```

But this is not working. What I want, if the _custom_stock meta field has any value then set backorder true on that product. The _custom_stock is a custom meta field, added to woocommerce options. I can save, modify, etc. so the meta field is work.

What I am missing?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you for your response. Still not work. This method work with woocommerce_product_is_in_stock filter. With that I can set the product to in_stock. Do you have maybe further idea why is not working? Thank you

Comment: I really don't see the utility of that custom field as WooCommerce has a native feature to allow backorder at product level. Your code seems to be ok except for `$product->id` that should need to be replaced by `$product_id` or by `$product->get_id()`…

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec. We are update the stocks quantity daily from an xml file. The purpose is this to enable the backorder automatically if the product is available in our supplier warehouse.

Comment: Your code should work. I can help anymore sorry.

Comment: No problem sir. Thank you